# Make migrations painless when dealing with large user base

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wonder what's the best way to deal with slow migrations when you have a large user base?

For example, I am moving the email column of users to a user_emails table to allow multiple emails by user. So, I've a migration that look like this:

```
class MoveLegacyPrimaryEmailToUserEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      user_email = UserEmail.new
      user_email.user_id = user.id
      user_email.email = user.legacy_primary_email
      user_email.save!
      user.primary_user_email_id = user_email.id
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

According to a simulation I've done, it will take ~ 66 minutes to run. To speed things up and avoid downtime, I've transformed this into raw SQL statements:

```
class MoveLegacyPrimaryEmailToUserEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      INSERT INTO user_emails (email, user_id)
        SELECT legacy_primary_email, id FROM users;
    SQL
    execute <<-SQL
      UPDATE users
        INNER JOIN user_emails
        ON users.legacy_primary_email = user_emails.email
        SET users.primary_user_email_id = user_emails.id;
    SQL
  end
end
```

Is this the correct way of dealing with this kind of issues or I am missing something obvious?

Comment: What about making sure that your code reading the email address first checks the separate table and if not it checks if it's in the user table. You then do the step: new table -> migrate -> remove column. In that way you might be able to reduce the downtime, if you only have to lock the table while removing the old email column. But again, this might be shaky.

Comment: I would guess that you would see a performance increase when you use `find_each` instead of `all` and `each`. `all` would load all records into memory first. Whereas `find_each` workes in batches, keeps the memory usage low and allows garbage collection between chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually see this tackled with a multi-stage deployment:

1. Deploy code that uses the new database structure if it's available, and falls back to the old data if not.
2. Migrate the data to the new structure.
3. Deploy code that only uses the new data structure.
4. Migrate the old structure into oblivion.

Having said that, I don't like babysitting hours-long deployments. If you can make it fast by writing raw SQL, do it. If that makes it fast enough to do the deployment in a single step, bonus!

Comment: For the use case presented in the question, maybe using raw SQL is fast enough to solve the problem. But in other situations where data are much bigger, you can deploy a code that use new structure if present or old structure if not and update data to the new structure. Using that, you have only schema modifications (create new and destroy old) and no real data migrations.